# Which statistical test should I use to compare the median values between two groups in my study?

Tags: statistical-significance, median

I am doing a retrospective study comparing the effect of medication adherence on the length of a patient's illness.

One group of patients took their medication compliantly, and I want to compare the number of days they were ill with that of a comparison group that did not take their medications compliantly.

Because the length of illness varied quite markedly between individuals, I thought it best for me to use median values. I was wondering what test I could do to determine the statistical significance of the difference between the groups?

Comment: There exist two-sample median test (search this site, wikipedia) based on chi-square test approach.

Comment: If there were any people whose duration of illness was not complete by the end of the study, you may want to consider analyses suited to censored data (survival analysis methods).

Comment: @Glen_b That's a good recommendation. It might be worth noting, however, that since many good tests of medians are completely insensitive to the tails, one might consider applying one of them first. If it does not require the numeric value of any of the censored data, then special survival analysis methods would not be needed; and if it does, then survival analysis would be called for. But Kate, if your interest truly is in *mean* illness length, you will not be well served by comparing medians. You shouldn't change your study objectives just because data are variable!